# Tests passed but code coverage is 0%

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, code-coverage, mstest

I am still learning to use MSTest and Moq for automated unit testing in my application. I have successfully mocked the code and run it. It is showing that the tests are passed , but the code coverage is 0%. This is my code below.What needs to be changed so that code coverage becomes 100%.

I know this question has been asked a couple of times before, but nothing seems to help me.So can anyone suggest me what am I doing wrong.

Any help is highly appreciated.Thanks.

PS: I'm using Sonarcube for knowing the code coverage.

```
using Moq;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis;

namespace MyNameSpace
{
    [TestClass]
    public class ApplicationTest
    {
        readonly Helper moqHelper = new Helper();
        [TestMethod()]
        public void GetDataFromDataBaseMoq()
        {
            Task<bool> returnValue;
            Mock<Application> mockType = new Mock<Application>();
            mockType.CallBase = true;
            mockType.Setup(x => x.GetDataFromDataBase()).Returns(returnValue = moqHelper.GetDataFromDataBaseMoq());
            if (returnValue.Result)
            {
                Assert.IsTrue(true);
            }
            else
            {
                Assert.Fail();
            }
        }
    }

    [ExcludeFromCodeCoverage]
    class Helper
    {
        internal async Task<bool> GetDataFromDataBaseMoq()
        {
            bool returnValue = true;
            return returnValue;
        }
    }
    public class Application : IApplication
    {
        public virtual async Task<bool> GetDataFromDataBase()
        {
            //if data retrive successfull, return true, else false
            return true;
        }
    }
    public interface IApplication
    {
        Task<bool> GetDataFromDataBase();
    }
}
```

Comment: After reading the answer by @CodeCaster you should make a note for the future. When a framework, compiler, code, whatever, tells you that X is happening (or in this case, *not* happening), your first reaction should always be "OK, let's assume the result is correct, what does that mean?". In this case, the simple answer is that your code isn't actually executing, so it is correct that there is a 0% code coverage. It sounds to me that you're focusing on why the code coverage is wrong, whereas the code coverage is in fact right, so instead you should focus on why your code doesn't execute.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not testing your application code, you're testing your mock. You could've seen this by setting a breakpoint in `Application.GetDataFromDataBase()` and debugging your test; you'd see it won't be hit.

You need to only mock dependencies, if any. So rewrite your test to actually call into your code:

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task GetDataFromDataBase_Returns_True()
{
    // Arrange
    IApplication classUnderTest = new Application();

    // Act
    var result = await classUnderTest.GetDataFromDataBase();

    // Assert
    Assert.IsTrue(result);
}
```

And you'll see the need for all the mocks and helpers goes away.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and explaination. I have changed the code as mentioned. However I'm getting this error while doing Run Tests. "System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Diagnostics.EventLog, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'. The system cannot find the file specified.
" .  Can you suggest what to do for this.

Comment: the error is thrown from this line-->  IApplication classUnderTest = new Application();

Comment: That's a different question altogether. You probably haven't shown all your code, and your `Application` class depends on that assembly, so you'll have to add a reference to it in your unit test project.